# Does Short-time Fourier transform impact quality of signal?

Tags: fourier-transform, perceived-quality

I am playing with [spleeter](https://github.com/deezer/spleeter) to separate voice from an audio signal.

They go to the frequency domain by computing the Short-time Fourier transform to create a spectrogram. As there are some approximation (windowing and overlap of window) in this calculus, I was wondering if it hurts the quality of the signal when one computes stft and then inverse-stft.

Answer (score 1):

STFT (short-time Fourier Transform) should not impact the quality of the reconstructed signal if properly implemented.

Furthermore, any signal $x[n]$ should be exactly recovered from its STFT analysis coefficients by a proper implementation of the associated inverse STFT;i.e., The forward and inverse pairs should exactly undo each other.

One should keep in mind about the overlap parameter and window functions however;i.e., if the window includes zeros, the inverse may not be possible at some overlaps. If the window does not contain any zeros, then the inverse is always computed.

Answer (score 1):

**By design, quality should be preserved**:  STFT is a redundant and fully inversible transform, when time-frequency data remains complex. Note this is not the case anymore when complex coefficients are turned into  absolute values or squared-magnitudes, as common for "spectrograms".

But as long as you preserve the redundant complex values, the novel representation better separates signal's components' and help further processing. And [optimal inverses, since many inverses can recover a redundant transformation](https://arxiv.org/abs/0907.3654), can help a lot.